# how to understand which recursive function program needs

Tags: c++, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I am testing some codes related to recursion function. I saw the recursion method for towers of hanoi problem but I am very confused, two recursive functions are using in if condition. The understanding of the program till now is first it set n to zero and after this I dont know how it increases the n and how it knows which recursive function it should call first. I am weak in understanding of recursive function,please help me in understanding the working of recursive function of given program.

// Recursive Towers of Hanoi

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void towersOfHanoi(int n, int x, int y, int z)
{// Move the top n disks from tower x to tower y.
 // Use tower z for intermediate storage.
    if (n > 0) // Base Case
    {
        towersOfHanoi(n - 1, x, z, y);
        cout << "Move top disk from tower " << x << " to top of tower " << y << endl;
        towersOfHanoi(n - 1, z, y, x);

    }

} // Recursive Procedure

void main(void)
{
    cout << "Moves for a three disk problem are" << endl;
    towersOfHanoi(3, 1, 2, 3);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Single-step the program in your debugger and inspect the parameters at the start of each recursive call.  This will give a very clear demonstration of how the recursions works.

Comment: Could you please tell me with example

Comment: Did you already follow the advice? You need to learn how to use the debugger eventually, so you might as well start now.

Comment: `void main(void)` - That's *not* a valid signature for `main`. Change to `int main()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is pretty wrong.

*It first set `n` to zero*. Actually it first sets `n` to 3

`towersOfHanoi(3, 1, 2, 3);` - this sets `n` to 3 (first argument)

*I don't know how it increases `n`*. Actually it decreases `n`,

`towersOfHanoi(n - 1, z, y, x);` - this sets `n` to `n - 1` (first argument again).

*how it knows which recursive function it should call first?*. It calls the first one first, same as any other code.

```
    towersOfHanoi(n - 1, x, z, y); // THIS ONE FIRST
    cout << "Move top disk from tower " << x << " to top of tower " << y << endl;
    towersOfHanoi(n - 1, z, y, x); // THIS ONE SECOND
```

Recursive functions work *exactly* the same as any other functions. There is no magic.

Comment: when n wiill sent in void towersOfHanoi(int n, int x, int y, int z) it will b 3 I know, but after calling three times this function  towersOfHanoi(n - 1, x, z, y); n will be 0 right? so after this how n increases, This wasmy question, I know how it is working but I dont know how n is increment

Comment: @Tayyab Yes, it's initially 3, and yes after calling 3 times it will be zero. **BUT** when you return from the function that value of `n` goes back to what it was before. Remember that there isn't one `n` variable. Every call to `towersOfHanoi` has its **own copy** of the `n` variable each with a different value. Again this is not something that's special about recursive functions. Any function call at all gets it's own copy of all it's parameters.

Answer (score 0):

i just read your question. Maybe your should know this.
 A few rules to be followed for Tower of Hanoi are −
Only one disk can be moved among the towers at any given time.
Only the "top" disk can be removed.
No large disk can sit over a small disk.
So we need to move the top n-1 disks from x to z, then we can move the n disk from x to y. finally move the top n-1disks from z to y.